# How can I access controls on a web page from another class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, dynamic, textbox, controls

I have a Webpage called departments that is calling another class in the codebehind. This class creates dynamic objects for the departments page and loads them into it. For example it will load grid views showing data, buttons, text box's, etc depending on data it reads from a database.

In this class I have created an upload DIV that contains a fileupload text box and a submit button. I am trying to upload what is in the fileupload text field (which the user selects a file from their pc and it loads in the location and file name) with the submit button I have created dynamically. In the click event of the submit button I need to figure out how to get that information from the text field off of the departments page. I am having trouble accessing this b/c it is not the department page code behind file and is another class separate from the departments page.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the information from the departments page into a method or property of your class. If the class you are calling is a UserControl, you could cast Parent.Page to Departments and access the field as a property.

Comment: Thanks. I think this works. I have passed a reference to me.forms.controls when I create my class. Then in that class I can access and drill through my controls to find the text field. The big problem I am having now is the information from that text field is blank. If it is a text box and the user types in text it is just "" and if it is a htmlinput field it is blank.

Comment: I keep reading everywhere I need to recreate the dynamically created objects so I can save the information from them. But when I click my button and it posts back none of the data is there until it recreates everything fresh... if that makes any sense?

Comment: That is correct. Any dynamic content has to be recreated. If you are using an FileUpload control, you will not access the Text property. You want FileName and then PostedFile is the actual contents.